# Which MacBook models support (directly or indirectly) dual DVI monitors, for a total of three screens?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've read through the "Questions with similar titles", and I don't see anything that directly answers my question.

Which current MacBook models (of any product line) support (directly or indirectly) attaching dual DVI monitors, for a total of three screens?

The monitors are third-party (Acer). By "directly or indirectly", I'm acknowledging that I'll likely have to buy additional cables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have two options, and they're both supported by all current MacBook Pro and MacBook Air models:

1. Use a DVI splitter to spread a single DVI output across multiple monitors (which will look like a single external monitor to the OS). The maximum resolution for an external monitor on all MacBook Pro or Air models is 2560 x 1600, so your maximum for the split displays will be 1280 x 1600 each (or maybe 2560 x 800).
2. Use a USB graphics adaptor for the third monitor, which will thus not have hardware graphic acceleration.

Comment: Does Thunderbolt not allow you to daisy-chain displays?

Comment: As far as I know, you can daisy-chain up to seven Thunderbolt *devices*, but only one of them can be a display.

Comment: @mike - not true. Thunderbolt displays can be daisy chain-able, as long as both the video card and the Thunderbolt controller support it. Apple's forthcoming Thunderbolt Display is daisy chain-able on 2011 MBPs, but not MBAs, which have a less capable Thunderbolt controller.

Comment: @MikeScott - any example of such a DVI splitter?

Comment: @Vlad – I've not used any, but you can find plenty by Googling for "DVI splitter".

Answer (score 1):

Any current MacBook Air or MacBook Pro will work. The first DVI monitor is simple; just get a [Mini-Display Port to DVI cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024604&p_id=5999&seq=1&format=2). The second one  will require a USB to DVI adapter, like the [IOGEAR USB 2.0 External DVI Video Card](http://www.iogear.com/product/GUC2020DW6/). The combination of these will allow you to use the two Acer monitors via DVI and the internal MacBook screen.

Comment: Have you had any experience with that IOGear USB to DVI device?

Answer (score 0):

As per Mike Scott's answer (specifically, point 2), an example of a USB graphics adaptor can be found [here](http://www.iogear.com/product/GUC2020DW6/).